# Proximity Based Search without user location swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, location, google-places-api

I'm working on an app which utilizes Google Places API in order to find locations based on a users search. I've implemented the search with the help of the UIAutocomplete (Google Places), but unfortunately, it is not location based (until the user provides authorization). I was wondering if there is a way to get the users location through their IP address or otherwise using Swift. I don't need a precise location, the city would be enough.

I've searched for a while and there doesn't seem to be any other way of doing this, so if you know of an API which can return the city the user is currently in, that would be great.

Thanks for all the help,
Vlad

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the system frameworks allow you to get the user's remote IP address anymore. A solution for you might be to use a website like http://mylocation.org/, which shows your IP address and location. Perhaps you can make a request to this website and parse out the HTML that comes back to get the location. Please note, this isn't the most accurate way of getting the user's location and you would be much better off using the `CoreLocation` framework.